# Unfortunately, Application has stopped - android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have created an app with facebook sdk integration in android studio, when i run the app on my device and click on the play button, the "application has stopped" error showing up and a list of errors showing in the debug in android studio!

I have edit the new errors with homeactivity class

Errors:

```
10-08 18:53:47.061 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.android.friendsmash/com.facebook.android.friendsmash.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.android.friendsmash.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:89)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
10-08 18:53:47.241 29083-29083/com.facebook.android.friendsmash E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

HomeActivity.java

```
package com.facebook.android.friendsmash;

import ....

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// Tag used when logging messages
private static final String TAG = HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Uri used in handleError() below
private static final Uri M_FACEBOOK_URL = Uri.parse("http://m.facebook.com");
private UiLifecycleHelper fbUiLifecycleHelper;

public UiLifecycleHelper getFbUiLifecycleHelper() {
    return fbUiLifecycleHelper;
}

// Fragment attributes
private static final int FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME = 0;
private static final int HOME = 1;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = HOME +1;
private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

// Boolean recording whether the activity has been resumed so that
// the logic in onSessionStateChange is only executed if this is the case
private boolean isResumed = false;

// Constructor
public HomeActivity() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String currentFBUserJSONString =
            savedInstanceState.getString(FriendSmashApplication.getCurrentFbUserKey());
    if (currentFBUserJSONString != null) {
        GraphUser currentFBUser =
                null;
        try {
            currentFBUser = GraphObject.Factory.create(new JSONObject(currentFBUserJSONString), GraphUser.class);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentFBUser(currentFBUser);
    }
    fbUiLifecycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            // Add code here to accommodate session changes
            updateView();
        }
    });
    fbUiLifecycleHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fbLoggedOutHomeFragment);
    fragments[HOME] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.homeFragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();

    // Restore the logged-in user's information if it has been saved and the existing data in the application
    // has been destroyed (i.e. the app hasn't been used for a while and memory on the device is low)
    // - only do this if the session is open for the social version only
    if (FriendSmashApplication.IS_SOCIAL) {
        // loggedIn
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            boolean loggedInState = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(FriendSmashApplication.getLoggedInKey(), false);
            ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setLoggedIn(loggedInState);

            if ( ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).isLoggedIn() &&
                 ( ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getFriends() == null ||
                   ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentFBUser() == null) ) {
                try {
                    // currentFBUser
                    currentFBUserJSONString = savedInstanceState.getString(FriendSmashApplication.getCurrentFbUserKey());
                    if (currentFBUserJSONString != null) {
                        GraphUser currentFBUser = GraphObject.Factory.create(new JSONObject(currentFBUserJSONString), GraphUser.class);
                        ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentFBUser(currentFBUser);
                    }

                    // friends
                    ArrayList<String> friendsJSONStringArrayList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(FriendSmashApplication.getFriendsKey());
                    if (friendsJSONStringArrayList != null) {
                        ArrayList<GraphUser> friends = new ArrayList<GraphUser>();
                        Iterator<String> friendsJSONStringArrayListIterator = friendsJSONStringArrayList.iterator();
                        while (friendsJSONStringArrayListIterator.hasNext()) {
                                friends.add(GraphObject.Factory.create(new JSONObject(friendsJSONStringArrayListIterator.next()), GraphUser.class));
                        }
                        ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setFriends(friends);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(FriendSmashApplication.TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fbUiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    if (!FriendSmashApplication.IS_SOCIAL) {
        showFragment(HOME, false);
    } else {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened() && ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentFBUser() != null) {
            showFragment(HOME, false);
        } else {
            showFragment(FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME, false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    fbUiLifecycleHelper.onResume();
    isResumed = true;

    // Hide the notification bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Measure mobile app install ads
    // Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getString(R.string.app_id));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    fbUiLifecycleHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    fbUiLifecycleHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Save the logged-in state
    outState.putBoolean(FriendSmashApplication.getLoggedInKey(), ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).isLoggedIn());

    // Save the currentFBUser
    if (((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentFBUser() != null) {
        outState.putString(FriendSmashApplication.getCurrentFbUserKey(),
                ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentFBUser().getInnerJSONObject().toString());
    }

    // Save the logged-in user's list of friends
    if (((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getFriends() != null) {
        outState.putStringArrayList(FriendSmashApplication.getFriendsKey(),
                ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getFriendsAsArrayListOfStrings());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    fbUiLifecycleHelper.onDestroy();
}

public void buyBombs() {
    // update bomb and coins count (5 coins per bomb)
    FriendSmashApplication app = (FriendSmashApplication) getApplication();

    // check to see that we have enough coins.
    if (app.getCoins() - 5 < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not enough coins.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    app.setBombs(app.getBombs()+1);
    app.setCoins(app.getCoins()-5);

    // save inventory values
    app.saveInventory();

    // reload inventory values in fragment
    loadInventoryFragment();
}

private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();

    // Do other changes depending on the fragment that is now showing
    if (FriendSmashApplication.IS_SOCIAL) {
        switch (fragmentIndex) {
            case FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME:
                // Hide the progressContainer in FBLoggedOutHomeFragment
                if (fragments[FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME] != null && ((FBLoggedOutHomeFragment)fragments[FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME]) != null) {
                    ((FBLoggedOutHomeFragment)fragments[FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME]).progressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                // Set the loggedIn attribute
                ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setLoggedIn(false);
                break;
            case HOME:
                // Set the loggedIn attribute
                ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setLoggedIn(true);
                break;
        }
    }
}

/* Facebook Integration Only ... */

// Call back on HomeActivity when the session state changes to update the view accordingly
private void updateView() {
    if (isResumed) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened() && !((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).isLoggedIn() && fragments[HOME] != null) {
            // Not logged in, but should be, so fetch the user information and log in (load the HomeFragment)
            fetchUserInformationAndLogin();
        } else if (session.isClosed() && ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).isLoggedIn() && fragments[FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME] != null) {
            // Logged in, but shouldn't be, so load the FBLoggedOutHomeFragment
            showFragment(FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME, false);
        }

        // Note that error checking for failed logins is done as within an ErrorListener attached to the
        // LoginButton within FBLoggedOutHomeFragment
    }
}

// Fetch user information and login (i.e switch to the personalized HomeFragment)
private void fetchUserInformationAndLogin() {
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // If the session is open, make an API call to get user information required for the app

        // Show the progress spinner during this network call
        if (fragments[FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME] != null &&
                ((FBLoggedOutHomeFragment)fragments[FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME]).progressContainer != null) {
            ((FBLoggedOutHomeFragment)fragments[FB_LOGGED_OUT_HOME]).progressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Create a RequestBatch and add a callback once the batch of requests completes
        RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();

        // Get a list of friends who have _not installed_ the game. 
        Request invitableFriendsRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session,
                "/me/invitable_friends", new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        if (error != null) {
                            Log.e(FriendSmashApplication.TAG, error.toString());
                            handleError(error, true);
                        } else if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                            if (response != null) {
                                // Get the result
                                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                                JSONArray dataArray = (JSONArray)graphObject.getProperty("data");

                                List<JSONObject> invitableFriends = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                                if (dataArray.length() > 0) {
                                    // Ensure the user has at least one friend ...

                                    for (int i=0; i<dataArray.length(); i++) {
                                        invitableFriends.add(dataArray.optJSONObject(i));
                                    }
                                }

                                ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setInvitableFriends(invitableFriends);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
        Bundle invitableParams = new Bundle();
        invitableParams.putString("fields", "id,first_name,picture");
        invitableFriendsRequest.setParameters(invitableParams);
        requestBatch.add(invitableFriendsRequest);

        // Check to see that the user granted the user_friends permission before loading friends.
        // This only loads friends who've installed the game.
        if (session.getPermissions().contains("user_friends")) {
            // Get the user's list of friends
            Request friendsRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session,
                    new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                            if (error != null) {
                                Log.e(FriendSmashApplication.TAG, error.toString());
                                handleError(error, true);
                            } else if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                                // Set the friends attribute
                                ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setFriends(users);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "name,first_name,last_name");
            friendsRequest.setParameters(params);
            requestBatch.add(friendsRequest);
        }

        // Get current logged in user information
        Request meRequest = Request.newMeRequest(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        if (error != null) {
                            Log.e(FriendSmashApplication.TAG, error.toString());
                            handleError(error, true);
                        } else if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                            // Set the currentFBUser attribute
                            ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentFBUser(user);

                            // Now save the user into Parse.
                            saveUserToParse(user, session);
                        }
                    }

                    private void saveUserToParse(GraphUser user, Session session) {

                    }
                });
        requestBatch.add(meRequest);

        requestBatch.addCallback(new RequestBatch.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onBatchCompleted(RequestBatch batch) {
                if ( ((FriendSmashApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentFBUser() != null) {
                    // Login by switching to the personalized HomeFragment
                    loadPersonalizedFragment();
                } else {
                    showError(getString(R.string.error_fetching_profile), true);
                }
            }
        });

        // Execute the batch of requests asynchronously
        requestBatch.executeAsync();
    }

}

// Loads the inventory portion of the HomeFragment. 
private void loadInventoryFragment() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Loading inventory fragment");
    if (isResumed) {
        ((HomeFragment)fragments[HOME]).loadInventory();
    } else {
        showError(getString(R.string.error_switching_screens), true);
    }
}

// Switches to the personalized HomeFragment as the user has just logged in
private void loadPersonalizedFragment() {
    if (isResumed) {
        // Personalize the HomeFragment
        ((HomeFragment)fragments[HOME]).personalizeHomeFragment();

        // Load the HomeFragment personalized
        showFragment(HOME, false);
    } else {
        showError(getString(R.string.error_switching_screens), true);
    }
}

void handleError(FacebookRequestError error, boolean logout) {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = null;
    String dialogBody = null;

    if (error == null) {
        dialogBody = getString(R.string.error_dialog_default_text);
    } else {
        switch (error.getCategory()) {
            case AUTHENTICATION_RETRY:
                // tell the user what happened by getting the message id, and
                // retry the operation later
                String userAction = (error.shouldNotifyUser()) ? "" :
                        getString(error.getUserActionMessageId());
                dialogBody = getString(R.string.error_authentication_retry, userAction);
                listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, M_FACEBOOK_URL);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                };
                break;

            case AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION:
                // close the session and reopen it.
                dialogBody = getString(R.string.error_authentication_reopen);
                listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                        if (session != null && !session.isClosed()) {
                            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                        }
                    }
                };
                break;

            case PERMISSION:
                // request the publish permission
                dialogBody = getString(R.string.error_permission);
                listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if (fragments[HOME] != null) {
                            ((HomeFragment) fragments[HOME]).setPendingPost(true);
                            ((HomeFragment) fragments[HOME]).requestPublishPermissions();
                        }
                    }
                };
                break;

            case SERVER:
            case THROTTLING:
                // this is usually temporary, don't clear the fields, and
                // ask the user to try again
                dialogBody = getString(R.string.error_server);
                break;

            case BAD_REQUEST:
                // this is likely a coding error, ask the user to file a bug
                dialogBody = getString(R.string.error_bad_request, error.getErrorMessage());
                break;

            case CLIENT:
                // this is likely an IO error, so tell the user they have a network issue
                dialogBody = getString(R.string.network_error);
                break;

            case OTHER:
            default:
                // an unknown issue occurred, this could be a code error, or
                // a server side issue, log the issue, and either ask the
                // user to retry, or file a bug
                dialogBody = getString(R.string.error_unknown, error.getErrorMessage());
                break;
        }
    }

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.error_dialog_button_text, listener)
            .setTitle(R.string.error_dialog_title)
            .setMessage(dialogBody)
            .show();

    if (logout) {
        logout();
    }
}

// Show user error message as a toast
void showError(String error, boolean logout) {
    Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (logout) {
        logout();
    }
}

private void logout() {
    // Close the session, which will cause a callback to show the logout screen
    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();

    // Clear any permissions associated with the LoginButton
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    if (loginButton != null) {
        loginButton.clearPermissions();
    }
}

}
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Some object is pointing null reference. It is a implementation related problem. Follow the facebook documentation to resolve it or provide the you have done.

Comment: i can post the classes here

Answer (score 0):

As they say above, you have null pointer exception in your activity.Log says a method you have in your GameFragment class' which is "getRandomFriendIndex line 298" has a value that not assigned yet.Check it first than if you can't find send us your class so we can help you better.

Comment: hey i have edit the question with complete class... please check!

Comment: have you changed your log?

Comment: your log says , in your HomeActivity line 89 you did not decleared something.And by the way, as a friendly advice use commend lines and mix up everything in your code.First do initializations than do method declerations.

Comment: yes i have changed log... i think  the old error solved

Comment: have you checked what i said mate?

Comment: i am saying man,look at the line 89 in your class.this is your wrong code.